# How would I check the event length in on method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, events, methods

```
apply() {
  this.$el.on('touchstart mousedown', (e) => {
    var type = e.currentTarget.length; // Gets undefined;
    console.log(type);
    this.start(e);
  })
}
```

I'm trying to get **the length of events** in `on` method on the above code. Is it any commands to get the number of events(length), not the numbers of alphabets in the string?

Comment: it sounds little abstract with your question. Do you mean the number of elements that fire the same event?

Comment: @ducmai No it's not. The element has multiple events as in `touchstart` and `mousdown` from the above code.

Comment: ah ok, an interesting question. I just know a way without coding is using chrome developer toolbar which shows all listeners attached to an element